# "may" or "may well"

Tags: difference

Today I've found out that **may well** means **probably**. I know that **may** is also used to express probability. What is the difference between using "may well" and "may" then?

Some of the examples I've run into are:

> You may well be right.
>
> He may well have missed his bus.

I'm wondering if the meaning of these sentences is the same as the meaning of

> You may be right.
>
> He may have missed his bus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the basic meaning is the same.

*Well* is simply an adverb modifying *may*. It means that the event is not merely possible, which is all that the bare *may* implies, but quite probable.

Note that this must be distinguished from sentences which employ *may well* in a sense which has nothing to do with probability:

> You may well say that.

Here the meaning of *may* is permissive, and *well* has its ordinary meaning as the adverbial form of *good*. The sentence means:

> I acknowledge that what you say is quite true. ... *or, more simply:*
>   Well said!